# REST client use camel framework

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am not very strong in rest communication. The task is create some sort of REST client using camel framework. First of all I took a look at cxf framework, but I am not sure will I able to  send request with changeable count of params?(I need do it for some requests). So the question is: what do you recommend use? CXF, axis2, http4, ahc or maybe something else? Also I don't have too much time to implement this client, so I don't have too much time to studying framework.

Comment: CXF sounds like the way to go, since the `cxfrs` component allows you to specify endpoints easily. I have used csf WS and I am betting it's very similar.

Comment: yep, as I understand for cxf I should create data class to send request. In my case I cannot do it because I don't know what property will be send in advance. For example it can be: class Request { String prop1; String prop2} or class Request {String prop3: String prop4}

Comment: REST is pure HTTP. So I would think all you need is the http4 component if you are implementing the client.

Comment: Thank you Ralf. I read more about Http4 yesterday. I guess it fit me